# Unity3D + NHibernate, crash loading "Unity 3.5 .net full Base Class Libraries"

Tags: nhibernate, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to marry Unity3d and NHibernate. After lot of magic it works in Editor, but crashes in Windows standalone .exe.

Main data-access libs I have:

```
MySql.Data.dll
I18N.dll
I18N.West.dll
System.Data.dll (2.0.5, for Unity)
NHibernate.dll (3.4.0)
```

The crash upon win app startup is:

```
TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories' from assembly 'NHibernate'.
  at NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver..ctor () [0x00000] in d:\Downloads\nh\NHibernate-3.4.0.GA-src\src\NHibernate\Driver\MySqlDataDriver.cs:27 

.........  omitted System.Reflection chain .......


  at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver (IDictionary`2 settings) [0x00020] in d:\Downloads\nh\NHibernate-3.4.0.GA-src\src\NHibernate\Connection\ConnectionProvider.cs:107 
Rethrow as HibernateException: Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver, NHibernate, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
  at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver (IDictionary`2 settings) [0x00052] in d:\Downloads\nh\NHibernate-3.4.0.GA-src\src\NHibernate\Connection\ConnectionProvider.cs:113 

  at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.Configure (IDictionary`2 settings) [0x0004f] in d:\Downloads\nh\NHibernate-3.4.0.GA-src\src\NHibernate\Connection\ConnectionProvider.cs:64 

  at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.NewConnectionProvider (IDictionary`2 settings) [0x000bd] in d:\Downloads\nh\NHibernate-3.4.0.GA-src\src\NHibernate\Connection\ConnectionProviderFactory.cs:50
```

Since it cannot load System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories, I think it can't get System.Data. At the same time my System.Data is 100% loaded clearly, because there's another authentication code which perfectly works with DB directly, w/o involving NHibernate.

**Can it be because** NHibernate is built with System.Data from .Net Framework visual studio profiles, while Unity project uses 2.0.5 version?

I've tried to build NHibernate with System.Data from "Unity 3.5 .net full Base Class Libraries". It's built successfully, but Unity also crashes when I put that System.Data.dll to plugins:

```
InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder:Remove (string): IL_0000: ret
```

It's strange, isn't Unity supposed to read libs from c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v3.5\Profile\Unity Full v3.5\System.Data.dll?

At the same time, I can't build NHibernate with c:\Program Files (x86)\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\unity\System.Data.dll. By default it loads v2.0.0 from GAC. When I try to explicitly write 2.0.5 version in .csproj, it fails:

```
Warning 2   The primary reference "System.Data, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 processorArchitecture=x86" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "System.Transactions, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which has a higher version "2.0.5.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.   NHibernate
```

I'm desperate - **how should I build NHibernate and what libs to use to make it working in Unity?**

Hope, someone has the answer.
Thanks in advance!
Yura

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after week of periodical trying I finally made it working:

1. Build NHibernate for .Net 3.5 (NOT "Unity profile", just regular 3.5)
2. Put 3.5 System.Data.dll from GAC to "plugins" folder in Unity

That's it.

I'm still wondering why Unity cannot accept libs from ""Unity 3.5 .net full Base Class Libraries" .Net profile, but at least it doesn't block me anymore.